I lost my dog in Minecraft
I lost my dog, Rusty, but I don't have a name tag on him. How do I find him? I've tried using /TP commands, but they don't seem to work. Rusty is a rusty wolf if that changes anything.

Hello Bailey_0458. In what way do they "now work"? What are those commands that didn't work? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say? We just need these little details to help understand. Details get dogs back home, lol.

Oops. There is a typo, I mean "In what way do they, 'not work'"
